# Excel power query authenticates fine on home page but not on API

Tags: microsoft-excel, authentication, api, power-query

I'm trying to extract data into Excel from a rest api, on a website protected by SSO (SAML, Azure AD). When using "Get data from web", Power query authenticates fine on the base domain name, but refuses to work on the api endpoint.

1. Confirming it works in Edge
   I go to the website (https://website.com) => SSO login and I can see the website fine
   I go to the rest API endpoint (get https://website.com/rest/2.0/users) => It works fine and I can see the json payload
2. Not working in Excel
   I click "Get data from web" and enter "https://website.com" => It authenticates me automatically, power query loads the website and allows me to load the html code.
   I click "Get data from web" and enter "https://website.com/rest/2.0/users" => it asks for authentication method (anonymous, windows, basic, web api, organizational account). They all fail to authenticate me against the website.

I cannot explain the difference of behavior between "https://website.com" and "https://website.com/rest/2.0/users", this is the same server with the same authentication mechanism.
Does anyone have a clue how to make power query use the same authentication mechanism or allow me to navigate the site with the initial authentication?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you test in IE?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes, I just tried with IE 11 and it worked fine. When loading the homepage, it logged me in automatically with SSO. Then going to the rest api endpoint resulted in a json response.